# Trouble with Guard Break

Tags: dark-souls-2

I was on my way playing Dark Souls 2 PC version when I had a great trouble with Guard Break and Leap attack.

I've did quite a bit of googling, and I understood that; to do a Guard Break I've to hit the forward button and the attack button. In my case It's W and the Left Mouse button. But doing the above gives me a general attack and not a Guard Break. The same happens with the Leap attack.

Guard Break is so essential in PVP so it would be helpful if anyone explains to me what is going wrong and how to correct it.

Comment: [Related, possible duplicate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172414/how-to-backstab-on-pc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue that the mouse controls tend to have a quite bit of input delay due to how strong attack is a double click so the game wait a bit to see if you're going to double click.

One thing you could do is use keyboard buttons instead, W + H if you're using the default keybinds. If you can, I suggest creating a macro that does it and bind it to some extra mouse button, or some easy to reach key.

Using a controller is another workaround, though they come with their own set of issues...

See more on the [wiki](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Guard_Break).

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the game detecting a "double click".

You can turn off double click detection so that a single click registers instantly instead of waiting that 100 ms to detect a double click.

However, this option resets itself every game, even though it says it is off.  Every time you start the game, you have to turn it on and off again.